# SQL Server Case Statement Inside Where Clause Generates Error

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using the below SQL but getting error in case statement inside where clause.

```
create procedure MyProcedure 
    @ApprovalFilter as nvarchar(50), 
    @BothPendingAndApproved as nvarchar(50)

Select 
    * 
from 
    myTable
Where
    data = "A"
    and 
        case @BothPendingAndApproved 
            when 'Both' then ApprovalStatus <> 'Rejected'
            when 'Specific' then ApprovalStatus like @ApprovalFilter
        end
    and 
    Data2="B"

End
```

Why this part is failing?

```
    case @BothPendingAndApproved 
        when 'Both' then ApprovalStatus <> 'Rejected'
        when 'Specific' then ApprovalStatus like @ApprovalFilter
    end
```

Comment: First of all, don't use `CASE` like this. It only makes the code harder to read. Second, `CASE` isn't a boolean expression. It must return a value and that value must be compared to something. Finally, T-SQL doesn't have a boolean type. `ApprovalStatus <> 'Rejected'` doesn't return a value.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, Thanks for your reply.  Any Suggestion to handle this situation will be helpful.

Comment: Use explicit `AND` and `OR` logic, @Sixthsense . `CASE` is an *expression* and returns a *scalar value*. It's not a "statement" (like a `Switch` statement) that operates as a control flow operation.

Comment: It's a *lot* simpler to write the `AND ... OR` conditions than `CASE`

Comment: Thank to everyone for your suggestions & replies :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CASE` is not a statement but an expression, which returns a scalar value. You could refactor the `CASE` expression for use as a predicate:

```
Select 
    * 
from 
    myTable
Where
    data = 'A'
    and 
        case  
            when @BothPendingAndApproved = 'Both' and ApprovalStatus <> 'Rejected' THEN 1
            when @BothPendingAndApproved = 'Specific' and ApprovalStatus like @ApprovalFilter THEN 1
        end = 1
    and 
    Data2='B'
```

IMHO, it's a bit clearer to use an `OR` condition:

```
create procedure MyProcedure 
    @ApprovalFilter as nvarchar(50), 
    @BothPendingAndApproved as nvarchar(50)
AS
Select 
    * 
from 
    myTable
Where
    data = 'A'
    and (
            (@BothPendingAndApproved = 'Both' and ApprovalStatus <> 'Rejected')
            OR (@BothPendingAndApproved = 'Specific' and ApprovalStatus like @ApprovalFilter)
        )
    and 
    Data2='B'
    OPTION(RECOMPILE); --consider this option to optimize the query
```

Note the use of single quotes for character literals for ANSI compatibility and use of SQL Server features like filtered indexes, indexed views, etc.

Comment: For my eyes the first approach which you given is very clearer.  Since I am a VBA & VB.Net user the first one is easy for me to understand in first sight itself. Thank you  :)

Comment: Note that the first solution won't be SARGable and thus could perform significantly worse than the latter solution, @Sixthsense . Explicit `AND`/`OR` methodology is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the comments CASE is just not working like that, you can use "simple" AND/OR conditions:

```
Where
   data = "A"
   and 
   (
     (@BothPendingAndApproved  = 'Both' AND ApprovalStatus <> 'Rejected')
     OR 
     (@BothPendingAndApproved = 'Specific' AND ApprovalStatus like @ApprovalFilter)
   )
   and 
   Data2="B"
```

Comment: Applied the above suggestion in my real data and it's working fine. Thank you :)